# Connect OpenLiberty to RabbitMQ over JMS

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, open-liberty

I'm writing a Java EE 8 application that I want to connect to a RabbitMQ bus. The application is deployed in OpenLiberty. Since the application uses Java EE 8, I want to use JMS for connecting to RabbitMQ. I have previously [connected to RabbitMQ over JMS in Tomcat](https://github.com/mthmulders/rabbitmq-over-jms) as a proof-of-concept, so I know it must be possible.

According to the documentation and blogs I found, I need a *Resource Adapter* to connect OpenLiberty to basically everything else than its internal JMS engine. I have found the [AMQP 1.0 resource adapter](https://github.com/amqphub/amqp-10-resource-adapter) and wanted to give it a try.

My server.xml:

```xml
<featureManager>
  <feature>beanValidation-2.0</feature>
  <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
  <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
  <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
  <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
  <feature>jms-2.0</feature>

  <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
  <feature>socialLogin-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- the resource-adapter-1.0.0.rar comes from the aforementioned GitHub project -->
<resourceAdapter id="amqp" location="${server.config.dir}/resource-adapter-1.0.0.rar">
  <classloader apiTypeVisibility="+third-party"/>
</resourceAdapter>

<jmsConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/JmsFactory">
  <!-- using .amqp as that is the ID for the resource adapter -->
  <properties.amqp ConnectionFactory=""
                   JndiParameters=""
                   DeleteTemporaryDestinations="true"
                   UserName=""
                   Password="" />
</jmsConnectionFactory>
```

Then, in my application code, I have

```java
@Inject
@JMSConnectionFactory("jms/JmsFactory")
private JMSContext context;
```

As soon as I invoke `context.createQueue("ExampleQueue")` (or whatever method call), I get

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: jms/JmsFactory
```

I've also tried doing a manual lookup, like so:

```java
final InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
final Context environment = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");

final QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) environment.lookup("jms/JmsFactory");
final Queue queue = InitialContext.doLookup("jms/ExampleQueue");
```

That fails at the `environment.lookup` with `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:comp/env/jms/JmsFactory`.

What am I doing wrong, or overseeing here?

Comment: what features do you have configured?

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for the question. I've updated the server.xml snippet.

Comment: Can you add jndi-1.0 to the list of features and see if that works?

Comment: @Alasdair I've enabled jndi-1.0 and restarted OpenLiberty. I'm getting the exact same Exception.

Comment: I’ve been trying myself, but I’ve got nothing injected at all. Haven’t got to the bottom of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between how Liberty expects a JMS Resource Adapter to be defined and how this resource adapter defines itself. Liberty expects a JMS Resource Adapter to use JMS classes in the ra.xml as the interface definition, so `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`. Instead this RA uses `org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory`. At runtime this is a `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`, but not in the ra.xml.

There is a simple workaround, just use the JCA connectionFactory element. I found the following configuration works:

```
<connectionFactory jndiName="jms/JmsFactory">
   <!-- using .amqp as that is the ID for the resource adapter -->
   <properties.amqp DeleteTemporaryDestinations="true"
       ConnectionFactory="factory1"
       JndiParameters="java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory;connectionFactory.factory1=amqp://localhost:5672"              
       UserName=""
       Password="" />
</connectionFactory>
```

There is a bug in Liberty for this issue [12088](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/12088), but I would suggest just using the JCA connectionFactory element to get going.